# Kotlin no-args plugin doesn't work with Maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

I want to add no-arg constructor for Kotlin class in Spring Boot app. I followed these [instructions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/no-arg-plugin.html) and have next configuration.

Version of Kotlin: **1.5.30**.

**pom.xml**

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <args>
        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
      </args>
      <jvmTarget>11</jvmTarget>
      <compilerPlugins>
        <plugin>spring</plugin>
        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
        <plugin>all-open</plugin>
        <plugin>no-arg</plugin>
      </compilerPlugins>
      <pluginOptions>
        <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.Entity</option>
        <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass</option>
        <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.Embeddable</option>
        <option>no-arg:annotation=com.abc.xyz.NoArg</option>
      </pluginOptions>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

**NoArg Annotation**

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class NoArg
```

**Target Class**

```
@NoArg
class DemoClass(
  val type: String,
  val title: String,
)
```

But when I try to invoke `val demoClass = DemoClass()` in test got next error:

```
Kotlin: No value passed for parameter 'type'
Kotlin: No value passed for parameter 'title'
```

Maybe some tweaks are required in IDEA?

Comment: any luck with this issue? I am having same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I ended up with using constructor with all default values. Also I've made a ticket (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-19882) but there is no fixes no extra information.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/jpa I saw here that they are also using default value for ID even though it is auto generated.